# How to copy dll's along with a c++ cli dll to whatever project includes the c++cli dll?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My c++/cli dll depends on a bunch of unmanaged dll files. I know how to copy the dlls from their source location to the c++/cli dll location when building it via post build xcopy to targetdir but when I include the c++/cli dll in a .net project (in the same solution), it only puts the c++/cli dll there, leaving others behind. How could I make the managed dll project drag along all the unmanaged dll's to wherever its deployed?

Comment: The build system is powerless to detect dependencies on native DLLs.  You already know how to use a post-build event, just do it again.  Or put them in the right spot in the first place.